# JPA : Unable to find entity after saving in DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have written a function in a Spring boot application as follows:

```
@Component
public class AspectHelper {

private final MyRepository myRepository;

public AspectHelper(
      MyRepository myRepository) {
   this.myRepository = myRepository;
}

@Async
public void save(MyEntity entity) {
  try {
    myRepository.save(entity);
    Optional<MyEntity> savedEntityOpt = myRepository.findById(entity.id);
    ...
  } catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error occurred while saving", e);
  }
}

}
```

The above function is getting called from another bean in a flow that is not in any Transaction.

The issue is, I am able to get a valid entity id immediately after saving the entity in DB, while I am trying to fetch the same, I am getting the exact saved entity.

But while checking the DB, I am not able to find the entity.

I have no clue why this is happening. Could anyone please help here?

Comment: You need to save in transaction. The second thing is that you can use `saveAndFlush` repository method.

Comment: `save` vs `saveAndFlush` explanation https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-save-saveandflush

Comment: When you are saving the entity, does it have an id? Btw. that thing with transaction and `saveAndFlush` is wrong

Comment: @Andronicus Immediately after saving the entity, I am able to get the associated id, with which I am doing the find query in the immediate next line.

Comment: Are you sure about not in a transaction, normally not in a transaction it persists entity after save method

Comment: Hi @omer yes this is not in a transaction.

Comment: interesting, can you add caller class snippet of save method and yml/properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are using the REPEATABLE_READ isolation level which is the default for MySQL. In that case, you have to understand that the connection will only see data that was committed up to the point where you started the transaction. Try using auto-commit in your SQL editor and/or switch to READ_COMMITTED